# Heroku Rails 5 LoadError: Could not load the 'listen' gem

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new to Heroku and have followed the **[Getting Started guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5#database)** to the letter. However when I deploy my application with `git push heroku master` it begins building the application and stops after trying to precompile assets with the following error:

```
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        LoadError: Could not load the 'listen' gem. Add `gem 'listen'` to the development group of your Gemfile
remote:        /tmp/build_78073b13aac28e116288169779278ade/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
```

I have verified that the gem is in fact inside the development group in my Gemfile and have tried moving the `gem 'listen'` outside the development scope [as per answers on related questions](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24063) but the problem persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To resolve this issue you can either:

- Comment out/remove the line `config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker` in `config/environments/development.rb`
  or
- Set RAILS_ENV=production in your heroku config variables. `heroku config:set RAILS_ENV=production`
  or
- Copy the `config/environments/production.rb` into a new file `config/environments/staging.rb` and set `RAILS_ENV=staging` in your heroku config variables.

Personally I prefer the latter.

Good luck

Comment: In my case we had `config.file_watcher` line in production.rb, commenting that out solved the issue. As i assume we don't need no watcher on production environments.